# command binding in wpf button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to bind a command in WPF but it does not hit. There are other controls in the XAML which have bindings and everything works fine. Not able to figure out what I'm missing .. please help

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="btnStart" Content="Start Getting Data" Margin="78.4,6.4,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding StartPolling}" />
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Content="{Binding Path=LastRefreshed}"></Label>

 public ICommand StartPolling
        {
            get
            {               
                    _startPolling = new RelayCommand(
                        param => StartPollingWell());
                } return _startPolling;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are creating a new command instance each time the getter is called

Comment: True, but I'm not sure why that would cause his function to not be called. It feels like there must be some more code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Is your command located in the Button's DataContext? My guess is that it is not and the command is not actually being bound to the button.

Comment: the label and the button are present in a user control. The datacontext is the same VM for both. The label displays correctly but the button binding does not hit

Comment: Sorry guys ! Found the problem. There was a mistake in my datacontext. I changed the Viewmodel name to something meaningful and didn't update in the grid context !

Comment: Aha!  Whenever my bindings don't work as expected, I always check the output window for binding errors first.